# How to get data from dynamically created text-boxes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating textbox dynamically by getting data from MySQL. suppose I have 2 rows in DB table, ABC and XYZ then 2 textboxes were created successfully but now I want to take data and doing some operations on it. I am set ID to textboxes like TB1,TB2 but in inspect tools id are like ContentPlaceHolder2_TB1, ContentPlaceHolder2_TB2.

I am getting some similar solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276545/get-value-of-dynamically-created-textbox) but it won't works.

and this my code:

```
while (reader.Read())
        {
            TextBox tf1 = new TextBox();
            Label lb1 = new Label();
            lb1.Text = reader.GetString("attribute_name")+":";
            lb1.Attributes["style"] = "color:#000;font-weight:800;";  
            tf1.ID = "TB"+c;
            tf1.Attributes["placeholder"] = reader.GetString("attribute_name");
            tf1.Attributes["class"] = "form-control";
            tf1.Attributes["style"] = "width:35%;border:2px solid #ccc;";
            div1.Controls.Add(lb1);
            div1.Controls.Add(tf1);
            c = c + 1;
        }

protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string s = ((TextBox)div1.Controls["ContentPlaceHolder2_TB1"]).Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w2JkLcp-UA

using this link first of all create a simple DB on SQl server Then see that I think you can solve your problem after that.

Comment: Add some raw code, if link fails then it will be helpful to user

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at

[Get Value Text of dynamically created TextBox in ASPNet using C and VBNet](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Value-Text-of-dynamically-created-TextBox-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

This will serve your need.

```
foreach (TextBox textBox in div1. Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    message += textBox.ID + ": " + textBox.Text + "\\n";
}
```

This will provide you result.